# How do I get notifySuccess to send verification code?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am following [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node) to implement Microsoft Graph interaction. I have managed to follow and display a page with my verification code, but the Teams SDK doesn't seem to want to post the code to my bot automatically.

I have the following lines in my oauth success page, as per the sample

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/teams-js@1.4.2/dist/MicrosoftTeams.min.js" integrity="sha384-DcoNUuQTjpW5Sw3msonn/2ojgtNvtC5fCGd5U9RUpL3g1hla1LzHz8I9YIYSXe6q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("instructionText").style.display = "initial";
            }, 5000);

    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess("{{verificationCode}}");
</script>
```

According to the sample, the bot receives an invoke message with name = signin/verifyState, but I do not. The sign-in page does close though.

Any ideas on why the page will not notify my bot of the code automatically?

Comment: I've been trying to test but am running into Azure issues that prevent me from testing adequately. It's likely related to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1553). Try debugging or `console.log()` every incoming message in `RootDialog.onMessageReceived` and see if you can narrow down what type the message is.

Comment: That being said, that sample is from the Teams team and uses BotBuilder V3. Personally, I'd recommend basing this kind of thing around the [Bot Auth](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication) and [MS Graph](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) samples.

Comment: @mdrichardson thanks for your reply. I'm using botframework v4, I've just copied elements from the sample. Everything seems to work fine up until the point described, at which point my ngrok console doesn't show any incoming requests for the notifysuccess either. I'm trying to do my auth without having to use the Azure portal, so I don't believe I can follow the Bot Auth sample you linked due to OAuthCards requiring a connection name setup in the Azure portal. Is there something I could be missing?

Comment: I'm guessing that it has something to do with the issue I posted. Teams used to use Action.OpenUrl in their Auth cards, but now those don't work and you have to use Action.Signin. If you can link to your code, I can take a look. I'm fairly certain it's in the bot code, not the html. Just remember to remove all of your auth info.

Comment: @mdrichardson I've stripped out the relevant parts from my project and uploaded them to a new [repository on Github](https://github.com/BrendanHart/TeamsBotGraphAuth). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd say it's not related to the issue I posted, due to the fact the SignInCard uses Action.Signin and *not* Action.OpenUrl. So that's good. Have you tried opening in [Teams for Web](https://teams.microsoft.com/go#) and watching the developer console? I'm attempting to repro, but working on the auth portion.

Comment: @mdrichardson I've tried this, and see the following errors in the developer console in the image at [this link](https://imgur.com/mHVxJeb).

Comment: I have been stuck with a similar issue for a while now. I have written down some more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348857/signin-verifystate-is-not-invoked-after-notifysuccess.

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi I have solved my issue now, I can provide the source in GitHub in a couple hours if that's helpful to you

Comment: @BrendanHart Thanks! That would really helpful. I will take a look at it and maybe have some questions.

The thing is, I do not want to use an OAuth flow but have some way of passing down token information (maybe a jwt token generated by our servers at login event) and pass it down to teams. I am not completely sure how secure this way is, but for what I am doing setting up an OAuth provider is a big cost.

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi This code may not be the proper way to do things, and it may contain some code which was left in for testing purposes/unfinished. However, here is the code responsible for my sign in:
https://pastebin.com/yA2P3R1f - for handling the users and their tokens
https://pastebin.com/623ntfmL
https://pastebin.com/Bk7DVgxs - One of the routes which handles the /callback endpoint

Sorry I haven't been able to provide a detailed explanation of this, as it's been around 6 months since I've looked at this code. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi You may also find this Github repo useful https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node although I believe it's an older version of the bot framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this took so long. Got it.

So, the issue is that you're looking for a `message` activity, but Teams is sending an `invoke` activity, which isn't caught in `onMessage`. Instead, in your BotController, use something like:

```js
this.onUnrecognizedActivityType(async (turnContext, next) => {
    console.log(`GOT : ${ JSON.stringify(turnContext.activity, null, 2)}`)
});
```

This produces:

```
GOT : {
  "name": "signin/verifyState",
  "type": "invoke",
  "timestamp": "2019-06-07T22:19:53.810Z",
  "localTimestamp": "2019-06-07T22:19:53.810Z",
  "id": "f:490708197841asdfasdfasdf15",
  "channelId": "msteams",
  "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/",
  "from": {
    "id": "29:1AvIMwjQc1iBRcFYBe-0opf4YzVU130fNasdjkhfkldjshfjkahgsdfjklasdkjfasdfcS_7MO9DKFFNL6Ow",
    "name": "asdfasdfasdfasdf",
    "aadObjectId": "asdfasdfasdfasdf"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationType": "personal",
    "tenantId": "asdfasdfasdfasdfasd",
    "id": "asdfasdfasdfasdf"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "asdfasdfasdfasdf",
    "name": "asdfasdfasdfasdf"
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "locale": "en-US",
      "country": "US",
      "platform": "Windows",
      "type": "clientInfo"
    }
  ],
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": "asdfasdfadsfasdf"
    },
    "source": {
      "name": "message"
    }
  },
  "value": {
    "state": "asdfasdfasdfasdf"
  },
  "locale": "en-US"
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the time spent looking into this. I've gave it a go, and still not seeing anything hit my ngrok server or in my application's console log. Is there any chance of uploading a working sample, or is it possible I'm missing something from my manifest that's preventing my Teams client from sending the invoke activity?

Comment: In my comment above which shows the developer console logs, it would seem like Teams is just failing to send the invoke request.

Comment: @BrendanHart Can you get it working in Emulator? The only thing I had to do was add that code. In the app registration, set `https://<ngrok url>/callback` as the redirect URI, add `User.Read openid profile` to the API permissions. I'm not sure if these were necessary, but I checked Access Tokens and ID tokens in the Auth tab, set Default Client Type to Yes and allowed "Accounts in any directory". And then in the Portal > Web App Bot > Settings, set the endpoint to my ngrok.

Comment: Here's my branch: https://github.com/mdrichardson/TeamsBotGraphAuth/tree/mdrichardson

Comment: As for the manifest, you might need to add your ngrok as a trusted domain. I didn't even use a manifest...just went to new chat and pasted in my appId. But yeah, if your bot isn't even seeing a response of any kind, it's maybe a permissions or ngrok thing.

Comment: Did some more testing...removed all of the options and permissions from the app registration and it still worked. I also get the same Invoke errors if I test in Teams Online, but it all still works fine.

Comment: I also tested using a manifest vs. pasting the appId in the To: of a new chat and it worked fine, too.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this. I'm at a little bit of a loss where to go next if it seems to work fine on your end. Have you seen the errors I've received in the developer console I added as a comment to my question?

Comment: Yep, I saw the exact same errors and everything *still* worked. The only things I can think that might be different are: 1) App Registration not having "Accounts in any org directory", or 2) ngrok breaking things (I'm using an [Azure Service Bus Relay](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/04/16/debugging-your-locally-hosted-v4-bot-using-azure-relays/), or 3) Your org/Active Directory having some kind of permissions issue, 4) Local firewall issue (Fiddler or something blocking things?).

Comment: I just tried it on my own test tenant as opposed to my company's tenant, and it worked! I'm going to mark your answer as accepted, but do you have any idea what steps I should get the admin to take to resolve it on my company's tenant?

Comment: In your app registration, 1) Under Authentication, do you have it set to "Accounts in any organizational directory", and 2) under Permissions, are you able to set User.ReadBasic.All without admin consent? I'll ask around and see if anybody has other ideas.

Comment: Yep, all seems fine there. I'm able to select both User.Read as well as User.ReadBasic.All without admin consent.

Comment: An update to this, after looking in the sign in logs for my account in my work's AAD, I have seen [this error](https://imgur.com/9b30tI1). Still investigating how to resolve this. EDIT: Just checked other tenant and this error is also present so might not be the cause.

Comment: I've recreated this issue in my own tenant now by creating the app as a user who's not an admin.

Comment: Are you testing this on Edge browser? Could you please share your Bot Id which we can check at our end?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I have tested in Opera, as well as the Teams desktop client. The Bot ID I have in my company's tenant that doesn't receive the signin/verify state message is fdf7bf33-3644-434e-83d5-b3575e33f008

Comment: Sorry, the ngrok link seems to be down. Could you please download [Auth Bot app manifest](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/raw/master/manifest/AuthBot.zip) and see if it works fine for you in both the tenants?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Apologies I had turned my laptop off whilst commuting. I've updated with a new ngrok link which I will try to keep active. I will also look at the linked manifest, thanks.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT The manifest linked with bot ID 98f08689-d05a-4e86-8989-d45cc4a5f915 doesn't seem to work very well for me. I keep getting "Something went wrong" when I click AzureAD.

Comment: @mdrichardson Sadly not, I'm still facing the same issue with this. I put my investigations on hold because I wasn't making any progress, but if anybody would like me to setup my bot with a valid ngrok link to try for themselves, I'd be happy to do so and it'd be very much appreciated, maybe it'd be best to continue this conversation over email or something?

Comment: Bummer. I'll still help you with it. Feel free to email me at vDASHmicricATmicrosoftDOTcom. Replace the caps, appropriately (trying to avoid email scrapers), or just look in my profile.

Comment: Thanks @mdrichardson, I'll most likely continue this with you on Monday if that's okay! Appreciate your time.

Comment: @mdrichardson I've just found the time to come back to this issue, but it seems to have started working for unknown reasons when I deployed it. I will email if I encounter any further issues with this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BrendanHart No problem. Glad to hear it's working! We've been making some changes to OAuth on the backend...I don't think they're related to your issues, but it's possible it helped. We're also working on much more direct integration with Teams, so hopefully this will start to make things even easier!