# signin/verifyState is not invoked after notifySuccess

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

`notifySuccess` doesn't fire `signin/veriyState` event.

My `TeamsMessagingExtensionQuery` handler returns something like this:

```
...
return {
                composeExtension: {
                    type: "auth",
                    suggestedActions: {
                        actions: [
                            {
                                type: "openUrl",
                                value: "https://something.com/login/",
                                title: "Sign in to this app"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            } as MessagingExtensionResponse;
    ...
```

This response shows the `searchCmd` extension with a sign-in message correctly. On clicking the sign-in, the prompt shows the login page correctly as well, according to the url that was passed in the response.

However, when in the login page I try to pass some test token data using the `notifySuccess` api,the `composeExtension/query` command gets invoked (with the `state` property), but there is no `signin/verifyState` event getting invoked.

On the login/client side, I am using the following two lines of code:

```
MSTeams.initialize();
MSTeams.authentication.notifySuccess('<test_token>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this signin combo (trying to sign in for a message extension), but it *seems* to me that Teams won't actually invoke "signin/verifyState" in this case, and that's only for a "vanilla" bot authentication flow. In this case, it seems from the docs like you're meant to complete the authentication inside the "composeExtension/query" instead...

Comment: Thanks for the response!

That seems a bit strange to be, that the api works differently in different scenario. It makes reading the documentation very hard.

Comment: So as I said, I've not -tested- this exact, scenario, I could be wrong, but that's certainly how I read this. You're right that it is indeed confusing, but this space is also new and changing all the time. Right now, SSO works in tabs, but it's still coming in Bots, for instance. Did you have a chance to test this out?

Comment: I am seeing the token come down once in composeExtention/query event. But only once. I guess I could finish the sign in there

Comment: yeah, that's what I suggest. Maybe try it out, and let us know here. Out of interest, what is the expiry set to on the token?

Comment: There's no expiry at the moment and it's not even a real token, as I am still playing around with various components in our product and make some PoCs. Why do you ask? :)

Comment: I'm working with bot tokens also, trying to figure some things out myself

Comment: I am not an expert at this. I think the expiry of this token is a question of what you are exposing and how sensitive is the data. Usually we decided this based on a scenario.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208393/discussion-between-deepankar-bajpeyi-and-hilton-giesenow).